# Accessing MongoDB properties doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

here is my schema

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var messageSchema   = new Schema({
    status: {type: String, default: 'Pending'},
    latestUpdate: Date,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Requests', messageSchema);
```

Here is how I print the properties to the console:

```
hosSchemaModel.find(function(err, hosSchema) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('inside error') // return res.send(err);
        } else {
          console.log(hosSchema)
        }

    });
```

in the above code, `console.log(hosSchema)` prints the following:

[The result of console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N82FC.png)

When I try to access `hosSchema.status`, `undefined` is printed to the terminal.

The reason is explained [here (3rd point)](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/mongoose-tips-and-tricks-for-uncommon-cases/) but I can't seem to understand it.

can anyone guide me here please? How can I access the properties such as status

Answer (score 0):

`hosSchema` is an array, not an object.

If you want to access the status of, say, the first document in the array, you'd use this:

```
hosSchema[0].status
```